# How to call pass data to modal observer manually and fire observer

Tags: laravel

I am working on Laravel v4.2 project and I want to add a post into `elasticsearch`. But in my scenario post has multiple post media up to five and also post location and tag user users list. post, media and location and tags users entries have been done in the separate table due to foreign keys.
But my problem is that I put the modal observer on post modal and when I upload post then I only receive post modal information instead of the whole post including post, post media, post location and tag users list. So is then any best way to solve this issue that I receive all post data into the modal observer. One thing is considerable that tag users, post location and post media also has separate models and observer just put on post modal and the first entry is done in post table and after success then location, media and tag users below is my working code.

```
Post modal
    if ($this->post = Post::create($updated_post_params)) {
       //save post location , media
       if ($this->savePostRelations($inputs, $data)) {
           DB::commit();
    } else if (connection_aborted()) {
        throw new Exception('Connection abort!');
    } else {
       throw new Exception(Notifications::$error['multi_post_error']);
    }
```

Observer

```
Post::observe(new PostObserver);
```

Current observer data received

```
Array
(
    [post_type_id] => 1
    [user_id] => 87
    [text_content] => 
    [client_ip_address] => 192.168.1.46
    [local_db_path] => 18372547
    [updated_at] => 2018-04-25 07:44:45
    [created_at] => 2018-04-25 07:44:45
    [id] => 11041871
)
```

Expected Observer data

```
Array
    (
        [post_type_id] => 1
        [user_id] => 87
        [text_content] => 
        [client_ip_address] => 192.168.1.46
        [local_db_path] => 18372547
        [updated_at] => 2018-04-25 07:44:45
        [created_at] => 2018-04-25 07:44:45
        [id] => 11041871
        [media] =>[
                {
                  [id] => 12525
                  [file] => something.jpg
                }
                {
                  [id] => 12526
                  [file] => something.jpg
                }
        ]
        [location] =>[
                {
                  [id] => 12525
                  [fs_location_id] => hhyf415214425hhsd
                  [location] => Banglore 
                } 
        ]
    )
```

suggest any usefull link and solution.